# Rails translation performance impact <%= raw t( vs. <%= t(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, security, rails-i18n

I am building a multilingual application using rails-i18n Ruby on Rails.
Most of content (and DB entries) I have to translate is pure text, though part of it has some embedded html.

I was thinking of using `<%= raw t('translation_key') %>` instead of the straight `<%= t('translation_key') %>` to account for future changes that might include html.

If I adopt `<%= raw t('translation_key') %>` throughout the all website, am I going to get any (negative) impact when it comes to

1. website performance
2. website security

Answer (score 2):

You just just append _html to your tag keys to handle HTML in translation tags:

```
en:
  key_one: test text
  key_one_html: <p>test text</p>
```

Then the standard code will work:

```
<%= t('key_one_html') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Performance aspect:**

The performance impact should be negligible. Calling `raw` copies the parameter into a new string (an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` to be precise) with its `html_safe` flag set to true. On the other hand there is no longer HTML escaping performed on that string.

**Security aspect:**

There are more substantial drawbacks to using `raw` everywhere.

You say your translations are read from the database. Can the user edit these translations? If so...

- You risk HTML injections: A malicious user could just enter a `<script>` tag.
- *All* your translations must to be HTML safe from now on. That means you have to manually escape all your translations, i.e. you have to replace <,>, and &.

**Alternatives:**

There are other options if you need to incorporate HTML into your translations:

- Use the `_html` suffix *judiciously* to prevent automatic escaping
- Use localized views and partials, i.e. `index.en.html`, `_footer.de-DE.html` to translate larger parts of your views.

To streamline translation of database entries, you try

- [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize)
- [hstore_translate](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate) (PostgreSQL only)

**Conclusion:**

Using `raw` everywhere will lead to a lot of problems along the road. Save yourself a lot of trouble and just use it "as needed".

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the globalize gem for bigger text / html sections of content.

https://github.com/globalize/globalize/blob/master/README.md

It also supports eager loading if you're worried about performance.